# How to GET id if it's not added to database yet? (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, insert

For example I have two databases:

customer table (id is auto increase)

```
---------------------------------------
----- id ----- name ----- surname -----
----- 1  ----- BOB  ----- test1   -----
----- 2  ----- Jhon ----- test2   -----
----- 3  ----- Nick ----- test3   -----
---------------------------------------
```

and product table (id is not null and you have to add it manually)

```
---------------------------------------------
----- id ----- product ----- date       -----
----- 1  ----- orange  ----- 10/10/2014 -----
----- 2  ----- apple   ----- 12/10/2014 -----
----- 3  ----- melon   ----- 26/10/2014 -----
---------------------------------------------
```

*EXAMPLE are made up i have much more complicated and bigger table.

Question is:

Using one **add.php** file I would like to add

Name = ____
Surname = _____

and after GET id from the field where name and surname (from table customer ) was added and using it add product and date (to product table) using same id.

I understand how to add information to multiple tables: [HERE](https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/databases/mysql/threads/178612/insert-data-into-two-tables-using-php-and-mysql)

But how add information to the tables 1 and after using ID from **table1** add **tables2** this is where I'm confuse.

Comment: use mysqli_insert_id() to get the id from last query

Comment: @AleksandarVasić: Thats the answer! You could also select the highest id (max(id)) but using mysql_insert_id() ist the cleaner way. A bit of googling would've answered this too.

Comment: Please if it's possible, can you make simple, just simple example of using mysqli_insert_id(). Using my question as sample.

Comment: why just not auto increment the product id?

Comment: @C4ud3x  be careful, the `max(id)` solution leaves a potential race condition that might damage data integrity in a busy system.

Comment: @itachi: The ids from table1 should match the ids of table2. Thats the condition of his question.

Comment: @OllieJones: As I said: Aleksanders answer is the better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `mysql_insert_id();` which gives you id of last query

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

example from php.net

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

so basicly you execute first query, get id with `mysql_insert_id()` and write second query

Comment: $myid = mysql_insert_id();
and you will have id of your last query in $myid

Comment: you dont need to add link as argument, because the default link is the lat one which was connected

Comment: @Denis look closer, you have linked to `mysqli_insert_id`, not `mysql_insert_id`. If you are using mysqli then yes, the link is required, or instead just use `$link->insert_id`

Answer (score 2):

To insert your first row, use this query, as normal.

```
INSERT INTO customer (name, surname) 
              VALUES ('Marie', 'Antoinette')
```

It will set the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` value for your connection. Then to insert your next row use this query, which incorporates `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

```
INSERT INTO product (customer_id, product, date)
             VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Cake', '1770-04-18')
```

This lets you do the second insert without retrieving the `LAST_INSERT_ID` explicitly. But if you have multiple `product` rows for one customer, you need something slightly different in your SQL.

```
INSERT INTO customer (name, surname) 
              VALUES ('Marie', 'Antoinette');

SET @custid =: LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO product (customer_id, product, date)
             VALUES (@custid, 'Cake', '1770-04-18')
INSERT INTO product (customer_id, product, date)
             VALUES (@custid, 'Guillotine', '1770-04-19')
```

This is a good way to do things because it works properly on a busy system where more than one database client might be inserting customers. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is maintained by MySQL connection-by-connection.  It's also good because you don't have to retrieve, and then send back, the last inserted id value.